# CSS not recognising classes

Tags: html, css, class

I feel a bit silly asking this as the answer is bound to be obvious. I set a h3 tag with a class on a WP template but for some reason the header tag is getting picked up as the default setting but the class is not and I can't understand why.

Html:

```
<h3 class="contact-heading">Get in Touch</h3>
```

CSS:

```
.contact-heading h3{color: #3C0; font: 2.0em Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;font-weight:    
normal;letter-spacing: 5px; text-transform:uppercase;}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask - read this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change css to:

```
h3.contact-heading { .... }
```

---

`.contact-heading h3` means "apply these styles to all `h3` elements inside an element with the class `contact_heading`"

h3.contact-heading means "apply these styles to all `h3` elements which have the class `contact_heading`"

Comment: I know it would be simple. Thanks for taking the time to explain the answer, Curt.

Comment: Sorry, new to this forum. I just marked the tick. Hope that is right.

Comment: Yeah thats right :) And welcome to the StackOverflow community!

Answer (score 1):

The selector `.contact-heading h3` will select any `<h3>` element within an element that has the class `.contact-heading`.

If you change the selector to `h3.contact-heading` it will select the `<h3>` element that has the class `.contact-heading`.

Remember to NOT put a space bewtween h3 and .contact-heading, or you're changing the selector :)